# Kinetica Multi-head Lookup

Tags: kinetica

I'm currently evaluating Kinetica DB for an analytics project on a 3 node cluster to build a custom dashboard on top of it.

As far as I understand, there is a way retrieving the records from the data nodes directly, which is called "multi-head lookup".

When using the Java API, it only seems to connect and request the data from the first node (also checked with Wireshark). Any idea what is wrong?

The table is sharded on vendor_id and rate_code_id, when pressing the "dist"-button in the Admin-UI, it shows that everything is distributed properly.

This is my DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE "demo"."nyctaxi_sharded"
(
   "vendor_id" VARCHAR (4, shard_key) NOT NULL,
   "pickup_datetime" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   "dropoff_datetime" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   "passenger_count" TINYINT NOT NULL,
   "trip_distance" REAL NOT NULL,
   "pickup_longitude" REAL NOT NULL,
   "pickup_latitude" REAL NOT NULL,
   "rate_code_id" SMALLINT (shard_key) NOT NULL,
   "store_and_fwd_flag" VARCHAR (1) NOT NULL,
   "dropoff_longitude" REAL NOT NULL,
   "dropoff_latitude" REAL NOT NULL,
   "payment_type" VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
   "fare_amount" REAL NOT NULL,
   "surcharge" REAL NOT NULL,
   "mta_tax" REAL NOT NULL,
   "tip_amount" REAL NOT NULL,
   "tolls_amount" REAL NOT NULL,
   "total_amount" REAL NOT NULL,
   "cab_type" TINYINT NOT NULL
)
TIER STRATEGY (
( ( VRAM 1, RAM 5, PERSIST 5 ) )
);
```

This is the Java code snipped:

```
GPUdb gpudb = new GPUdb("http://myserver:9191", new GPUdbBase.Options().setUsername("user").setPassword("pw"));
        Type tableType = Type.fromTable(gpudb, "demo.nyctaxi_sharded");
        RecordRetriever<GenericRecord> recordRetriever = new RecordRetriever<>(gpudb, "demo.nyctaxi_sharded", tableType);
        List<List<Object>> lookupValues = Arrays.asList(
                        Arrays.asList("VENDOR1", 0),
                        Arrays.asList("VENDOR2", 0),
                        Arrays.asList("VENDOR3", 0),
                        Arrays.asList("VENDOR1", 1),
                        Arrays.asList("VENDOR2", 1),
                        Arrays.asList("VENDOR3", 1),
                        Arrays.asList("VENDOR1", 2),
                        Arrays.asList("VENDOR2", 2),
                        Arrays.asList("VENDOR3", 2));
        
        lookupValues.forEach(lookup -> {
           try {
               GetRecordsResponse<GenericRecord> record = recordRetriever.getByKey(lookup, "");
               System.out.println(record);
           } catch (GPUdbException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        });
```

Once this is working, I would like using this lookup on a pre-calculated materialized view. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that the gpudb.conf file (on the server, usually in /opt/gpudb/core/etc) has:

> enable_worker_http_servers = true

This can be "false" by default, and if "false" then Java's RecordRetriever will just use a single node, which is what you described you are seeing.